# KDE Kup Backup couldnt read my home folder failed to Index everything

Tags: kde, backup

I am trying to back up to my secondary 1TB hard drive.
I am getting this error message:

```
Kup is starting bup backup job at Saturday, August 6, 2022 11:20:03 PM MST

bup "-d" "/media/krillavilla/1 TB Secondary" "init"
bup "-d" "/media/krillavilla/1 TB Secondary" "index" "-u" "--exclude" "/home/krillavilla/.cache" "--exclude" "/home/krillavilla/.local/share/Trash" "--exclude" "/home/krillavilla/.local/share/baloo" "--exclude-rx-from" "/home/krillavilla/" "/home/krillavilla"
usage: bup index <-p|-m|-s|-u|--clear|--check> [options...] <filenames...>

Modes:
    -p, --print           print the index entries for the given names
                            (also works with -u)
    -m, --modified        print only added/deleted/modified files
                            (implies -p)
    -s, --status          print each filename with a status char
                            (A/M/D) (implies -p)
    -u, --update          recursively update the index entries for the
                            given file/dir names (default if no mode
                            is specified)
    --check               carefully check index file integrity
    --clear               clear the default index

Options:
    -H, --hash            print the hash for each object next to its
                            name
    -l, --long            print more information about each file
    --no-check-device     don't invalidate an entry if the containing
                            device changes
    --fake-valid          mark all index entries as up-to-date even if
                            they aren't
    --fake-invalid        mark all index entries as invalid
    -f, --indexfile ...   the name of the index file (normally
                            BUP_DIR/bupindex)
    --exclude ...         a path to exclude from the backup (may be
                            repeated)
    --exclude-from ...    skip --exclude paths in file (may be
                            repeated)
    --exclude-rx ...      skip paths matching the unanchored regex
                            (may be repeated)
    --exclude-rx-from ...  skip --exclude-rx patterns in file (may be
                            repeated)
    -v, --verbose         increase log output (can be used more than
                            once)
    -x, --xdev, --one-file-system  don't cross filesystem boundaries

error: couldn't read '/home/krillavilla/'

Exit code: 97
Kup did not successfully complete the bup backup job: failed to index everything.
```

I cannot find any associate articles for this issue.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but you have /home/krillavilla twice at the end of the options

Comment: @PonJar I though its initially my secondary HD. then, its proceed to indexing it aka reading the HD. I though its permissions issue but i fixed it. I deleted the previous backup plan and start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; that is how I landed on this question. As there was no concrete resolution in the existing answer, I played around with the configuration a little. I can confidently say that when we **turn off / disable** the setting "*Exclude files and folders based on patterns*", this error goes away.

i.e. do not enable the patterns option under Advanced configuration!
i.e. you should not see `--exclude-rx-from` in the executed command when you check the log file.

In terms of .config/kuprc file, you should remove this entry if it exists:

```
Exclude patterns=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I started a new backup plan after deleting my old one.
Despite the fact that I can see error messages in the log, the backup was successful:

```
Kup is starting bup backup job at Saturday, August 6, 2022 11:47:23 PM MST

bup "-d" "/media/krillavilla/1 TB Secondary" "init"
bup "-d" "/media/krillavilla/1 TB Secondary" "index" "-u" "/home"
Exit code: 0
bup "-d" "/media/krillavilla/1 TB Secondary" "save" "-n" "kup" "-vv" "/home"
b'/home/krillavilla/.config/google-chrome/Profile 2/IndexedDB/https_docs.google.com_0.indexeddb.blob/3/1e/1e7f': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/krillavilla/.config/google-chrome/Profile 2/IndexedDB/https_docs.google.com_0.indexeddb.blob/3/1e/1e7f'
Saving: 100.00% (147295054/147295054k, 566180/566180 files), done.    
WARNING: 1 errors encountered while saving.
Exit code: 1
Only harmless errors detected by Kup.
Kup successfully completed the bup backup job at Sunday, August 7, 2022 12:21:51 AM MST
```